# how to get bigger glsgroupheading in glossary

Tags: glossaries

I am experimenting with:

```
\renewcommand*{\glsgroupheading}[1]{\textbf{\glsgetgrouptitle{#1}}\\}%
```

To get bigger group headings in my glossary. Apparently I'm doing something wrong because it gets all screwed up:

[image: Gloassary]
I'm using the `\setglossarystyle{altlistgroup}` glossary style.
I think I have to renew another command, don't know which.

Comment: Please complete your code as a MWE. Just a question: For indices you would need a `\par` at the begin before `\textbf`; may that be your issue too?

Answer (score 1):

I hads to add a `\item` element:

```
\renewcommand*{\glsgroupheading}[1]{\item[]{\textbf{\glsgetgrouptitle{#1}}}}
```

That solved it for me.